# Searching from Bottom to Top in Python

Tags: python, search

I am trying to find a way to search up a file rather than down and display the line it finds.

So right now I search down a document and find the line I am looking for and print it. I want to be able to then from that location search up till I find different line print that, and then continue searching down the document.

I have looked all over for an answer and have found things in other languages but they do not work in Python.

```
with open(currFile, "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "(F)" in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i:i+5]: print >> outfile, l,
```

Comment: Your best bet might be to read the whole thing into memory with `.readlines`. It's much easier to work with a list than a file object.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code, it always gives a good starting off point for people to work on.

Comment: I am doing that to search forward through it.

Comment: After you put it in a list, use `reversed()` on it to get the list flipped around. Then search through it as you already are.

Comment: Indent each line with four spaces so that it formats properly in your question.

Comment: The flipping the list around with reversed() and searching back through it will work great thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get a reversed slice:

```
searchlines[i-1:i-5:-1]
```

e.g.:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(10)[4:2:-1]
[4, 3]
```

Instead of slicing you could also iterate through the indices in reverse order:

```
for j in xrange(i - 1, i - 5, -1):
    l = searchlines[j] 
    # see if the line is what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Often times list comprehension is your friend when working with files:

```
with open("MyFile.txt","r") as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

From there you use a for loop to iterate through the lines:

```
for i,line in enumerate(line):
    if SomeCondition:
        print(line)
        for prevLine in lines[i-1::-1]:
            if SomeOtherCondition:
                print(prevLine)
                break
```

Hope this helps :)